# Change all other colors in the image to black except ONE specified color in Python OpenCV/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I basically have a semantic segmentation mask and I would like to change all colors to black in the image except one color (the road - violet).

How do I do it in numpy or opencv?

[image]

Updated image [image: This image has tiny corrupted pixels on it]
Changed the code to

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

 colors = [
  (100, 100, 150),
  (32, 11, 119),
  (70, 70, 70),
  (100, 60, 0),
  (142, 0, 0),
  (255, 255, 255)
]

# colors = np.array(colors)
# all other colors
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=bool)

for color in colors:   
    mask |= (img == color).all(-1)

img[mask] = (255,255,255)
```

and the result is the following image with still the same minor corruption (or added colors (just peek at the top row pixels) that I want to remove)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
# special color
colors = [ (100, 100, 150), (32, 11, 119), (70, 70, 70), (100, 60, 0), (255, 255, 255) ]


# all other colors
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=bool)

for color in colors:   
    mask |= (img == color).all(-1)

img[~mask] = (255,255,255)
```

Output (shown by `plt.imshow`):

[image]

Comment: what does .any(-1) mean? Also did you get the image by opencv read?

Comment: @unsure_automata yes, image read with `cv.imread`. `all(-1)` checks whether all the cells along last dimension are `True`, which means that all the channel (b,g,r) match those of specified color.

Comment: How do you expand this to be all other colors except a set of five colors should be black?

Comment: For five colors, it's easiest to do a loop and aggregate the `mask`. See updated answer.

Comment: i tried it and it seems to change the whole image into black

Comment: ```
colors = [
  (100, 100, 150),
  (32, 11, 119)
  (70, 70, 70),
  (100, 60, 0),
  (255, 255, 255)
]


# all other colors
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=bool)

for color in colors:   
    mask |= (image != color).any(-1)

image[mask] = (255, 255 , 255)
```

this for instance has all white.

Comment: @unsure_automata see updated code: `mask |= (img==color).all(-1)`

Comment: it basically changes all those in the color list to my designated target (black/white) and the other colors outside of it remains. Changing | to & just retains the original image.

Comment: basically, i need to change ALL colors NOT in the LIST to white (which includes those corrupted pixels that had random colors)

Comment: Your output image does not look like the sample image. I ran the code on that image. Also, just read image with `img = cv2.imread('file.png')` without any extra parameter.

Comment: I saw the problem. it should be img[mask == False] = (255,255, 255)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. Updated the answer to reflect that.